# deploy zip to aws lambda automatically

Tags: deployment, aws-lambda

I have zipped my source code using python and moved Zip file to S3 bucket. And how can I automatically deploy this zip file to my already existing Lambda function.
could you please give an idea on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, you can use lambda console to upload a zip. Could you explain the automatically deploy usecase well. So I can help you.

Comment: Right now i'm doing the same way, using console i'm uploading my zip. I'm trying to automate the manual process. 1.Required code packing into zip and moving to S3 is completed. 2.Now to upload the zip from s3 to Lambda is pending as part of auto deployment.

Comment: Why don't you try serverless? It makes all this thing simply using cloudformation scripts. Simple commands serverless deploy in your system terminal will do the job.[use this doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/). Ask if you need help regarding this.

Comment: yah.. thanks. could you pls let me know how to implement or more details regarding this.

Comment: I have explained the concept and given examples reference, go through them and you can simply use serverless deploy every time you make changes to your code. There are many exciting features of serverless, you can create any AWS resource using serverless scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first install serverless.

```
npm install -g serverless
```

- check this repo for examples. I am providing a simple python lambda function example. [serverless examples](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-dynamodb)
- You can reference your lambda function from the files and also create necessary roles and invoke permissions and mention your resources in serverless.yml.
- To deploy the cloud formation script simply use below command from the directory of serverless.yml file

```
serverless deploy
```

- To delete the resources you deployed simply use following command from serverless.yml file's directory.

```
serverless remove
```

- This saves you a lot of time than creating your resources through console.
- You can also see different examples of nodejs etc in that repo.

Comment: Can i add my git repo url to pack the source into zip and deploy ? instead of lambda function creating in the yml ?

Comment: You need to have serverless.yml file and you are not creating lambda function in serverless.yml. you are just referencing(importing) function from a different file you have written.In the example repo you can see the lambda function codes in todos directory

Answer (score 0):

- You can setup S3 to trigger a different lambda function whenever a code is uploaded in the s3 bucket and configure this lambda function to upload that zip in s3 to your desired lambda function.
- If your usecase is you only have to do changes and update the code from bucket. You can use serverless instead of paying for another lambda function.
- Serverless uses cloudformation underlyingly.
- see this reference on how to setup a s3 trigger [create s3 trigger](https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers). Write your logic using boto3 client in this triggered lambda to upload the code to other lambda.